# Getting a JSONParseException when indexing fields from MongoDB collection in SOLR using DataImportHandler

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am seeing this exception while I am trying to index data from MongoDB collection :

```
Exception while processing: products document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{idStr,name,code,description,price,brand,size,color}
 ^
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.MongoEntityProcessor.initQuery(MongoEntityProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.MongoEntityProcessor.nextRow(MongoEntityProcessor.java:54)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:476)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:481)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:462)
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{idStr,name,code,description,price,brand,size,color}
 ^
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseString(JSON.java:387)
```

Following is my data-source-config file in dataimport directory in conf folder of my core :

```
<dataConfig>    
 <dataSource name="mymongodb" type="MongoDataSource" database="mongodb://*.*.*.*/testdb" />
     <document name="data">

      <entity 
      name="products"
      processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
      query="{idStr,name,code,description,price,brand,size,color}"
      collection="products"
      datasource="mymongodb"
      transformer="MongoMapperTransformer" >

        <field column="idstr" name="idstr" mongoField="idStr"/>
        <field column="name" name="name" mongoField="name"/>
        <field column="code" name="code" mongoField="code"/>
        <field column="description" name="description" mongoField="description"/>
        <field column="price" name="price" mongoField="price"/>
        <field column="brand" name="brand" mongoField="brand"/>
        <field column="size" name="size" mongoField="size"/>
        <field column="color" name="color" mongoField="color"/>

    <entity 
    name="categories"
    processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
    query="{'idStr':'${categories.idstr}'}"
    collection="categories"
    datasource="mymongodb"
    transformer="MongoMapperTransformer">

        <field column="type" name="type" mongoField="type"/>
    </entity>   
    </entity>
    </document> 
</dataConfig>
```

I am trying to join the field idStr of categories collection with the idStr of products collection(field name => idstr) and get  the above fields ( name,description,... from products and type field from categories).

Any comments/solution on this exception would be really appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your SOLR field is declared as `idstr` but you are referencing it in the `query` attribute of `dataConfig` as `idStr` (camelcase difference).

Comment: I had to use products.idstr as I would like to join idStr of categories to idstr(field name) of products(in the mongoDB products collection it is still idStr so I have used mongoField="idStr")like :                         query="{'idStr':'${products.idstr}'}" 
Also now I am seeing an exception :
The query failed '{idStr,​name,​code,​description,​price,​brand,​size,​color}'
com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{idStr,name,code,description,price,brand,size,color}
 ^ Is this syntax correct for indexing these fields from products?
query="{idStr,name,code,description,price,brand,size,color}"

Comment: OK... well the `query` is the problem according the stack trace. I'd concentrate there to fix it. Have you tried putting single quotes around the fields: `{'idStr','name',...`?

Comment: Yes I tried that now :  
query="{'idStr','name','code','description','price','brand','size','color'}"                                                                                                                  Exception while processing: products document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'idStr','name','code','description','price','brand','size','color'}
        ^..........
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'idStr','name','code','description','price','brand','size','color'}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this ...
Following is the working configuration in the data-source-config file :

```
 <entity 
name="products"
query="select idStr,name,code,description,price,brand,size,color from products">

    <field name="prodidStr" column="idStr" />
    <field name="name" column="name" />
    <field name="code" column="name" />
    <field name="description" column="description" />
    <field name="price" column="price" />
    <field name="brand" column="brand"  />
    <field name="size" column="size" />
    <field name="color" column="color"  />

  <entity 
  name="categories" 
  dataSource="mongod"     
  query="select idStr,ancestors from categories  where idStr = '${products.idStr}'">
    <field name="catidStr" column="idStr" />
    <field  name="ancestors" column="ancestors" />
</entity> 

</entity>
```

Comment: Thanks for all info shared here by each of u